# Whats the difference between 5π/3 vs -π/3?

Tags: trigonometry

The question says: Evaluate arctan( -√3) and I got 5π/3, but the back of the book says the answers is -π/3. Isn't that basically the same thing?

Comment: Range of usual principal value of $\arctan$ is $(-\frac{\pi}{2},
\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Comment: The difference between ${5\pi\over3}$ and $-{\pi\over3}$ is $2\pi$.

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{5\pi}{3}$ is certainly coterminal to $-\frac{\pi}{3}$ but consider that $\tan$ needed to be domain restricted to make it invertible. The standard convention is to restrict $\tan$ to $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$. As such, your values for $\arctan(y)$ should be in this interval.